# Why am I getting an error for accessing an instance variable inside my class (python)

Tags: python, pycharm, private-members, python-class

I am writing a class for a lazy square root, allowing me to use it in fractions for linear algebra without getting a messy float. I've run into two specific problems both related to pythons 'private' class attributes. The first is that I am getting a soft error from pycharm for accessing an unresolved class attribute. My constructor looks something like this:

```
class SquareRoot(Real):
    def __new__(cls, operand, coefficient=None):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self._value = (here i parse the value of operand)
        self._scalar = (here i parse the value of the coefficient if there is one)
        return self
```

Obviously a lot more happens with handling the input, and in the case that I get a non-integer, I try to return just sqrt(operand), throwing an error if this doesn't work, so my `__new__()` function will sometimes not return a SquareRoot object, but most often will.

My first problem is with my properties:

```
@property
def radicand(self):
    return self._value
```

Here I get a soft error about an unresolved attribute to SquareRoot._value. When I change the method to

```
@property
def radicand(self: 'SquareRoot'):
    return self._value
```

with the type hint, the error goes away. If I change the constructor so that it always returns SquareRoot types this does not change the error, so there shouldn't be a problem with the construction. From what I understand of 'private' attributes in Python, I should expect PyCharm (or any IDE) to throw a soft error if I do this:

```
x = SquareRoot(2)
x._value
```

but that I should be able to reference `self._value` anywhere within my class without any warnings. I have a .pyi stub file and whenever I let PyCharm try to correct my 'unresolved attribute' it tries to put an `__init__()` method in the stub with `self._value` initialized inside, so I'm wondering if somehow my stub file (which has absolutely nothing but type hints for methods) is making my .py file think its missing an attribute initialization.

My second problem is more of a concern that I have done something wrong. When I create an instance of SquareRoot like this:

```
x = SquareRoot(2)
print(x) # 'sqrt(2)'
SquareRoot._value = 5
print(x) # 'sqrt(5)'
```

I am somehow able to change the value of `x._value` like this, but from my understanding of class attributes, I should only be able to do this if value was a class attribute, shared across all instances, but it is created only within my `__new__()` method. My question here is more of: is this expected and if so, why?

Comment: I think PyCharm only looks in the `__init__` method for attributes, not `__new__`

Comment: You're only getting this warning from PyCharm, the script runs as expected, right?

Comment: `SquareRoot._value = 5` is possible by design. You can set any attribute at runtime in Python, even if it is not defined in the class/module/object at all

Comment: @Barmar yes the script runs as expected. all errors are soft warnings

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's any way to tell PyCharm about attributes that are created outside the `__init__()` method.

Comment: @Barmar that makes a lot of sense thank you. I'll probably use the type hints so its not throwing an error

Comment: @Marat thank you i hadnt learned that yet!

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting the attributes in `__new__` and *not* in `__init__`?

Comment: @chepner because my SquareRoot object is immutable and (as far as I know) ```__new__``` is preferred for immutables

Comment: It's not *really* immutable. `__new__` is *necessary* when you need to perform initialization via the parent class's constructor. You are adding attributes to the already constructed object; you can do that in `__init__`.

Comment: @chepner that makes a lot of sense. I thought about it and was leaning towards using ```__init__``` but I remembered a big reason I need ```__new__``` is because in situations where I get an irrational coefficient I want to return a float (equivalent of just using my SquareRoot object as ```math.sqrt()``` ) which I can't do with ```__init__``` but you're right I'm not actually doing anything with the constructor

Comment: Another question: what exactly does `SquareRoot` provide that an ordinary `float` doesn't? *Every* `float` is the square root of some other value (precision issues aside). Your class should encapsulate some behavior that doesn't already exist. For example, you might define an `Radical` class that stores two integers, an index `n` and a radicand `r` such that `Radical(r=3, n=2)` reprenstents the square root of 3 *exactly*. This class could override `__add__` et al. to provide exact arithmetic operations on `Radicals`.

Comment: @chepner I need a lazy square root so that I can put it in the numerator of a fraction. If it's evaluated as a float it's irrational and cannot be put into a fraction. I need this mostly for orthonormalized bases in linear algebra. And yes my class overrides all operators (although I don't override ```pow(base, power, mod)``` since mod is pretty tricky with irrationals).